# Change my layout used in ListView to RecycleView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm working in a project and I have an Activity with a ListView inside. I have another Layout file used in a Cursor Adapter for each row of data. This layout file has a Relative Layout as a parent view group.

I'd want use a Cardview to display data. But, can I use it alongside the ListView, adding the RecycleView in the Layout file used in Cursor Adapter, and in this case should I have remove the Relative Layout?

Thanks!

P.S. I am working with pre-lollipop devices

Answer (score 0):

You can design card view in customAdapter.xml as per your requirements with LinearLayout as parent layout. 
Note: While implementing the card view you should have LinearLayout as main layout in your card view layout.

You can refer this site to get the clear idea regarding List View implementation.  [List View](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)